# What led to the estranged marriage?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

> Why did Han and Leia separate?

After reading theories and reviews on the movie I see many people saying that they have separated and gone back to what they do best.

> Han goes back to smuggling and Leia goes back to being a Commander or something.

There was no reason for them to separate.

Comment: They clearly explained their reasons in their dialogue. Is there need for more?

Answer (score 4):

SPOILERS!

There are 3 reasons:

1. The main reason they separated was the fact that **their son, Ben fell to the Dark Side and destroyed (not 100% sure how) everyone studying in Luke's Jedi Academy and turned into a Villain Jr. named Kylo Ren**, repeating the path of his illustrious grandfather, Anakin "Creepy" Skywalker.

   > “I didn’t plan on coming here,” he explained. “**I know whenever you look at me, you’re reminded of him. So I stayed away**.” (novelization)
   >
   > She stared at him, shaking her head slowly. “That’s what you think? That I don’t want to be reminded of him, that I want to forget him? **I want him back**.”
   >
   > What could he say to that? What possible response could he give to a **willful denial of reason**? “He’s gone, Leia. He was always drawn to the dark side. There was nothing we could’ve done to stop it, no matter how hard we tried.” **His final words were the hardest to get out. “There was too much Vader in him**.”
   >
   > “That’s why I wanted him to train with Luke,” Leia said. “I just never should have sent him away. **That’s when I lost him. When I lost you both.**”
   >
   > Han dipped his head. “**We both had to deal with it in our own way.” He shrugged. “I went back to the only thing I was ever good at**.”
   >
   > “We both did,” Leia admitted.
   >   He met her eyes steadily. “We’ve lost our son, forever.”
2. A PART of the reason may also have been the fact that Leia knew that this fall was because of **long-term influence by Supreme Leader Snoke**, but never told Han - and Han blamed himself or both of them for Ben's fall as a result.

   > Leia bit her lower lip, refusing to concede. “No. It was Snoke.”
   >   Han drew back slightly. “Snoke?”
   >   She nodded. “He knew our child would be strong with the Force. That he was born with equal potential for good or evil.”
   >   “You knew this from the beginning? Why didn’t you tell me?”
   >
   > She sighed. “Many reasons. I was hoping that I was wrong, that it wasn’t true. I hoped I could sway him, turn him away from the dark side, without having to involve you.” A small smile appeared. “**You had—you have—wonderful qualities, Han, but patience and understanding were never among them. I was afraid that your reactions would only drive him farther to the dark side**. I thought I could shield him from Snoke’s influence and you from what was happening.” Her voice dropped. “**It’s clear now that I was wrong**. Whether your involvement would have made a difference, we’ll never know.”
3. A third reason is that they simply **aren't very compatible people** - two very strong and abrasive personalities (especially Leia, combining a perfect blasting cap of a Princess and a General). Remember their first meeting in ANH and the barbs they traded? While that kind of verbal joustling can be OK and even strengthen some couples, it can also frequently lead to marital stress and incompatibility.

   > “I see you’re in trouble,” Maz said. “I’ll help you find passage—avoid Snoke’s hunter squads—but this journey to the Resistance isn’t mine to take, and you know it.”
   >   “Leia doesn’t want to see me,” Han said uneasily.
   >   “Who can blame her!” Maz exclaimed. “But this fight is about more than you and that good woman. Han, go home.” (novelization)

   and see their exchanges:

   > Breaking the awkward silence, Han finally spoke to Leia.
   >   “You changed your hair.”
   >   Her gaze dropped from his face. “Same jacket.”
   >   “No. New jacket.”

   and even wore

   > From a corner, Han spoke up. “Told you.”
   >   Leia ignored him. “What a fool I was to think we could just find Luke and bring him back.”
   >   He moved toward her. “Leia…”
   >   She growled at him. “Don’t do that.”
   >   It stopped him cold. “Do what?”
   >   **Her voice was flat. “Be nice to me.”** Whirling, she stomped off. More than a little bewildered, he followed. Though he caught up to her easily, she didn’t stop, nor did she look in his direction.
   >   **“Hey, I’m here to help**,” he told her.
   >   She continued to march forward, her gaze set straight ahead. “**When did that ever help? And don’t say the Death Star.**”
   >   Frustrated, he stepped out in front of her to block her path. When he spoke again, his tone softened until he was almost pleading—as much as Han Solo was capable of pleading.
   >   “Will you just stop and listen to me for a minute? Please?”
   >   The change in tone did more to mollify her than anything else. She eyed him impatiently. “I’m listening, Han.”

Answer (score 2):

Marriages fall apart for many reasons; money troubles, health, career differences and distractions. These are all stressors on the marriage. For Han and Leia, two large stressors severely damaged their marriage and they were unable to recover. First, the fall to the Dark Side of their son, Ben Solo. Second, the loss of Luke Skywalker due to Luke's guilt over the destruction of the Jedi Academy.

The first alone may have been sufficient; in many ways going to the Dark Side was worse than if Ben had simply died. When Luke abandoned them in the aftermath, gone off on his own quest, the couple was unable to hold together.

Comment: A farmboy with no relationship experience and former hots for the wife who's also his sister? NOT someone I personally want for my marriage councelor :)  +1, good answer